# Serilog does not write application initial logs to console with appsettings

Tags: c#, .net, serilog

I have configured appsettings.json file to write console log. The application uses dotnet core 6.

```
{
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Console" ],
    "MinimumLevel": "Debug",
    "WriteTo": [
      { "Name": "Console" }
    ]
  }
}
```

And read from configuration like following.

```
builder.Logging.ClearProviders();

var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .ReadFrom.Configuration(builder.Configuration)
    .CreateLogger();

builder.Logging.AddSerilog(logger);
```

But when I run the application, inital logs does not write to console. I have a black empty console.

Answer (score -1):

Check the [documentation](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Configuration-Basics#creating-a-logger), and try to use Log.Logger as pointed by @Rippo.

---

Can you try configuring it through the `Host` in `Program.cs` ?

*(.net core 6, adapt it if you have a different version)*

```
builder.Host.UseSerilog((hostContext, services, configuration) => {
    configuration.MinimumLevel.Is(LogEventLevel.Debug)
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .WriteTo.Console()

    .WriteTo.Debug() // also try writing to the debug console and see if it output something
});
```

Comment: dotnet core 6, I updated the post